# Resubmit form with new values

Tags: c#, forms

I am working in c# mvc, I have createed a form, submitting that form leads to a listing page that contains the list of items fetched from database depending on the values filled in the form.

Now on this listing page I have multiple date buttons(2 days back and 2 days ahead to the date filled in form), on click of these buttons I want to resubmit or want to regenerate the list with new date rest form values remains same as filled previously.
Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to add sample code to show your current progress. But from what I could understand you could simply wrap a form around your buttons like so...

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Next</button>

    @Html.HiddenFor(YOUR_MODEL_VALUES)
}
```

Unlike ASP.NET Web Forms you can have multiple forms on a page.